# ORACLE 10g: How to get all directories

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am looking to find all oracle directories which exist in database. The database version is Oracle 10g.

The command `select * from all_directories;` returns only a couple of them. Can this be permission related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running it asa user with DBA privileges.

Comment: I don't have permissions. Is there another way?

Comment: Not that I know of. Ask your DBA ;)